# AWS ProjectionExpression with DynamoDBScanExpression

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table (named Student) with 17 columns. In this table I have columns like student_id, name, age ... . I want to get students with age > 18. This code snippet is giving `List<Student>`. But I want only `List<String>` i.e list containing only student_id's.

```
DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
    scanExpression.addFilterCondition("age", new Condition()
                                                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GT)
                                                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(age)));
```

I tried this: `scanExpression.setProjectionExpression("student_id");`

But it throws error. So what wrong am I doing here.
And if there is any way to do this task with DynamoDBQueryExpression
Also if I want multiple selective cols, suggest a method for the same

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample is not enough for me to see how you execute the scan expression. Is it using a [DynamoDBMapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html), if so the result of the scan always returns List of Objects of the class to which the table is mapped to. Providing a projection expression will only limit the attributes returned (Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html)). You still have to extract the student_id into a list after the scan result is returned.

```
List<Student> result = mapper.scan(Student.class, scanExpression);
List<String> studentIds = result
            .stream()
            .map(student -> student.getStudentId())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For more examples on Query and Scan refer to [this AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.QueryScanExample.html).

Comment: actually I am using this map step afterwards to get list<string>, but I am looking for solution which can get me only the student_id list in that scanExpression only with projectionExpression